# Detect "end decelerating" in a programmatically moved scrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, scroll

I had a manually dragged scrollview, now I want a scrollview moved programmatically when I click a button, by this code:

```
offset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x+320, 0);

[UIScrollView beginAnimations:@"scrollAnimation" context:nil];
[UIScrollView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[scrollView1 setContentOffset:offset];
[UIScrollView commitAnimations];
```

It works well but now the functions scrollViewBeginDragging and scrollViewEndDecelerating are not called. Begindragging is no problem for me, but I don't know how detect the end of de scrollview movement when it is fired programmatically.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried using setContentOffset animated method? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

Comment: I've had problems with that... I can't remember what it was, and i ended up doing it this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:` delegate method. That's exactly what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

Well... you kind of know when that's supposed to get called, right? Those callbacks are intended for touches, so they won't work, but you're telling it to finish 0.5, so why not schedule a call to the delegate method yourself?

```
[self performSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:) withObject:scrollView afterDelay:0.5];
```